# nextjs timer between each request of getStaticProps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, timer, request

our app need to do around 37000 pages generation with an array generated by getStaticPath
the getStaticProps need to do a request on our api for build each page, but we have currently some timeout request.
Then, i will try to add a little timer in each request (i think about 0.1 second) but i didn't find anywhere a nextjs parameter to do this
Anyone allready do this?

Comment: Why don't you use getServerSideProps instead ?

Comment: because we need to have all pages generated in static for SEO. each page need to have an distinct accessible url

Comment: Just artificially extend the time of each getStaticProps. Create a asyn sleep helper function.

Comment: allready tried to do that, but it is getStaticProps who lauch all requests, then if i add a timer on each request, the timer don't interact with getStaticProps loop, all requests will be delayed of x seconds

Comment: You could generate a smaller subset of the pages during build time, and use [`fallback: 'blocking'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking) in `getStaticPaths` so that the remaining pages get statically generated the first time they're requested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for your case I think you should use getServerSideProps, you told that you need Dynamic SEO for each page and that is exactly what getServerSideProps id for, the idea is to render specific meta that depend on the data you get from your request, here is an example below:

```
    export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    let { data } = await axios.get("YOUR_URL")
    return {
      props: {
        data,
      },
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

And in your component

```
<Head>
      <link rel="canonical" href={canonicalUrl} />
      <title>{title}</title>
      <meta name="title" content={data.productTitle} />
      <meta name="description" content={data.description} />
      ...etc
    </Head>
```

Comment: all pages need to be static for SEO we don't want to have them dynamic like for exemple https://mon-cadastre.fr/cadastre-64100-bayonne, and we need to have 36500 generated page as static. with getSeverSideProps no pages are generated at build :)

Comment: Ok je comprends plus ou moins, la génération static permet en effet de render la page plus rapidement et donc d'augmenter le score SEO de Google mais j'avoue n'avoir aucune idée de l'incidence que pourrait générer une génération de 37000 pages statiques, le seul truc c'est que chaque build va prendre un temps dingue à mon avis

Comment: Mais tu pourrait aussi très bien avoir un bon score SEO avec du getServerSideProps c'est là que je comprends pq tu veux absolument générer des pages statiques

Comment: nous voulons que par exemple les recherche "cadastre bayonne" sur google arrive sur notre page. si nous passons par getServerSideProps, la page n'existe pas, car elle est générée à la volée. nous voulons que toutes nos pages soient référencées :)

Comment: Je suis pas un expert en SEO mais la page sera référencée avec le temps je pense, de pars le nombre de gens qui la visite, les mots-clés choisit pour être dans la meta title/description, et de ce que je crois comprendre la génération d'un sitemap, ce qui va aider google pour crawler le site et trouver toutes les urls disponibles, enfin voila je suis pas un expert en la matière, c'est juste que la génération de 37000 pages me paraissait bizarre. Voici un lien next js pour le SEO si jamais, https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/introduction-to-seo

Comment: merci je vais regarder lundi :)